# Verify a signature file (PKCS7) with WinCrypt or CNG

Tags: sign, asn.1, cng, wincrypt

I need to verify a signed JAR file using Windows crypto API methods. I have only a basic understanding of encryption and signing matters. I'm also new to those crypto APIs (WinCrypt, Bcrypt, Ncrypt). Verifying the file hashes wasn't a problem, but the signature part is blocking me.

Thanks to OpenSSL, the PKCS7 RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315) and various other sources I was able to figure out the actual file contents of META-INF/LOCALSIG.DSA contained in the JAR. But after two weeks of digging, trial and error I'm still stuck and don't know what else to try.

OpenSSL has the nice command `openssl smime -verify -inform der -in LOCALSIG.DSA -content LOCALSIG.SF -noverify`, which does exactly what I want to do. Unfortunately, I couldn't find such a high-level command in the Windows APIs.

I've tried to use the `VerifySignature` family of functions from all three APIs, but I need to provide the public key for those, and I had no luck using any of the `ImportKey` functions. So I tried to manually dissect the ASN1 format using `CryptDecodeObjectEx`, in order to pass the individual parts as BLOBs to the API functions. While I had some success with this, I'm stuck again because I can't figure out how to parse sets. I don't want to write my own ASN1 parser from scratch...

So, how do I use a PKCS7 signature file with the Windows crypto APIs?

I guess it might be easier using OpenSSL, but then I would have to convince my employer to add OpenSSL to our codebase just for this one purpose...

---

***UPDATE***: The LOCALSIG.DSA file contains the signers certificate and the signed hash of the LOCALSIG.SF file. This can be verified using `openssl pkcs7 -inform der -print_certs -text -in LOCALSIG.DSA` or `openssl cms -cmsout -inform DER -print -in LOCALSIG.DSA`.

The certificate is self-signed by our company and in the certificate store. I might need to provide the whole chain of trust. That's why I added the `-noverify` option to `openssl smime -verify`.

In fact, there are two scenarios with different certificates (internal and external releases), one using DSA (sig file contains one cert), the other using RSA (sig file contains three certs). That means I can't hardcode which certificate or method to use. I need to extract that information from the provided file. How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As i understand from your question you need to verify PKC7 with detached signature. For this purpose you can use function [CryptVerifyDetachedMessageSignature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptverifydetachedmessagesignature).

Sample code:

```
CRYPT_VERIFY_MESSAGE_PARA vparam = { 0 };
    vparam.cbSize = sizeof(CRYPT_VERIFY_MESSAGE_PARA);
    vparam.dwMsgAndCertEncodingType = X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING;
    vparam.pfnGetSignerCertificate = nullptr;
    vparam.pvGetArg = nullptr;


    /* read your files somehow */
    std::vector<char> sig;
    if (!ReadFile("LOCALSIG.DSA", &sig))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to read file" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    std::vector<char> mes;
    if (!ReadFile("LOCALSIG.SF", &mes))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to read file" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    /* CryptVerifyDetachedMessageSignature requires array of messages to verify */
    const BYTE* marray[] = {
        reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(mes.data())
    };
    DWORD marray_len[] = {
        static_cast<DWORD>(mes.size())
    };

    if (!CryptVerifyDetachedMessageSignature(vparam,
        0, 
        reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(sig.data()),
        static_cast<DWORD>(sig.size()), 
        1, /* number of messages in marray */
        marray,
        marray_len,
        nullptr))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to verify signature, error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Verify success, signature valid" << std::endl;
    }
```

**UPDATE**
To verify certificate chain you need to use [CertGetCertificateChain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certgetcertificatechain)

Sample code:

```
PCCERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT pChain = nullptr;
CERT_CHAIN_PARA chainPara = {0};
HCERTSTORE hStore = nullptr;
/* you sig file */
DATA_BLOB db = {
    static_cast<DWORD>(sig.size()), reinterpret_cast<BYTE *>(sig.data())};

/* you can open your sig file as certificate store */
hStore = CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_PKCS7, X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, NULL, 0, reinterpret_cast<BYTE *>(&db));
if (!hStore)
{
    goto Exit;
}

chainPara.cbSize = sizeof(CERT_CHAIN_PARA);
chainPara.RequestedUsage.dwType = USAGE_MATCH_TYPE_AND;
chainPara.RequestedUsage.Usage.cUsageIdentifier = 0;

if (!CertGetCertificateChain(NULL,  /* use default chain engine */
                             pCert, /*  pCert - pointer to signer cert structure (the parameter that was obtained in the previous step) */
                             NULL,
                             hStore, /* point to additional store where need to search for certificates to build chain */
                             &chainPara,
                             CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_CHAIN_EXCLUDE_ROOT,
                             NULL,
                             &pChain))
{
    std::cout << "failed to build chain: " << GetLastError();
    goto Exit;
}

if (pChain->TrustStatus.dwErrorStatus == CERT_TRUST_NO_ERROR)
{
    std::cout << "certificate valid";
    goto Exit;
}
if (pChain->TrustStatus.dwErrorStatus & CERT_TRUST_REVOCATION_STATUS_UNKNOWN)
{
    std::cout << "certificate revocation status unknown";
}
/* you need to place root certificate to the Trusted Root Store */
if (pChain->TrustStatus.dwErrorStatus & CERT_TRUST_IS_UNTRUSTED_ROOT)
{
    std::cout << "untrusted CA";
}
/* and so on */

Exit : 
if (pCert)
{
    CertFreeCertificateContext(pCert);
}
if (pChain)
{
    CertFreeCertificateChain(pChain);
}
if (hStore)
{
    CertCloseStore(hStore, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! `CryptVerifyDetachedMessageSignature` does indeed extract all the info from PKCS7 file (viewable in the optional `ppSignerCert` param), it succeeds in verifying the original message and fails when I temper with the message. However, it doesn't seem to care about the certificate. It succeeds whether or not the certificate is installed or the purposes of the cert are enabled/disabled.Am I supposed to check the chain of trust with separate calls?

Comment: Thanks again, your answer solved my problem with the certificate / signed hash part. I already had the hash verification of individual files working using several BCrypt functions. I would upvote your answer too, but unfortunately don't have enough reputation to do that...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether we have all the information needed so I do not have any definitive answers. However, let's see if we can make progress towards a solution.

You asked:

> How do I know which certificate to load and from where?

You as the verifier need to have that trusted certificate in your possession in some form. With Windows, it would be good if that certificate were installed in your certificate store. This is what I assumed in my answer. If you do not know where the certificate is, then you will have to figure that out first, otherwise you will not be able to properly verify the signature.Somehow, the certificate needs to be provided to the verifier (you) by the signer, via a trusted channel.

You also wrote:

> OpenSSL has the nice command `openssl smime -verify -inform der -in
>   LOCALSIG.DSA -content LOCALSIG.SF -noverify`, which does exactly what I
>   want to do.

Are you sure this does exactly what you want to do? Since you are passing in the `-noverify` flag, all that this command does, is verifying that `LOCALSIG.DSA` contains a correct signature of the contents `LOCALSIG.SF`. However, it does not verify that this signature was created by an identity that you trust. Anybody with a valid certificate and key pair could have created that signature.

In order to verify the signature, including the signer's identity, with a stock-openssl version, you need to have the entire certificate chain available to you, in a format that openssl understands (PEM or DER), up to the self-signed root certificate. Then you can check it with the slightly different command

```
openssl smime -verify -inform der -in LOCALSIG.DSA -content LOCALSIG.SF -CAfile trusted-cert.pem
```

---

Your question is updated to indicate that the signing certificate is self-signed and in the certificate store. There are still multiple possible routes, but I will assume at this point that you know what the subject name is of the signer that you expect to have generated this signature. (If not, then please indicate what you *do* expect.) With that information, you can use the following steps to verify your signature:

First use [`CertEnumCertificatesInStore()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certenumcertificatesinstore) to look up the certificate in the certificate store. For example usage, see [Example C Program: Listing the Certificates in a Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccrypto/example-c-program-listing-the-certificates-in-a-store).

When you have a handle to that certificate, use [`CryptImportPublicKeyInfoEx2()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptimportpublickeyinfoex2) to get a handle to the required public key.

That handle, which is of type `BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE`, you can use with [`BCryptVerifySignature()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptverifysignature) to do the verification.

Comment: I added `-noverify` because the certificate is self-signed (company-wide, in the certificate store), which makes openssl quit with an error. Apparently I need to provide the complete concatenated certificate chain in this case, which I intended to solve later, but maybe it's relevant.

Comment: I used `openssl pkcs7 -inform der -print_certs -text -in LOCALSIG.DSA` to inspect the file. The `cms` command gives pretty much the same results, with a bit more information.

Comment: @Simpleton I have added some more information to the answer, based on your UPDATE 2.

Comment: I had already tried to use the functions you mention, but to do so, I need to extract the method, the certificate, the public key and the signed hash from the signature file. It's all in there, ASN.1 encoded, I can view it using OpenSSL, but how do I get at that info? That's my original question.

Comment: @Simpleton Your question has been modified over time but currently states "The certificate is [...] in the certificate store." Is that still true? If your certificate is in the certificate store, then you do not have to do most of the stuff that you describe in your comment.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and sorry for my confusion and continous editing of my question, you have definitely helped me discover things as we went along. I would like to upvote your answer for your troubles, but unfortunately don't have enough reputation to do that...

Comment: @Simpleton No worries, that is how SO works, and you are welcome. Glad to hear you got your problem resolved.